# Using JQuery to access HTML dropdown menu value and then call PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

After unsuccessfully attempting to solve my issue strictly with Ajax, I have made the move to JQuery.  Unfortunately I have a limited understanding of JQuery and was hoping someone could tell me what it is I am doing wrong.  I have spent multiple days on this problem and have essentially got nowhere!

My task in theory is simple, all I want to do is take the value of a HTML drop down menu and call a php function with the appropriate row of the drop down menu.  The php function print_wp_cart_button_for_product outputs an add to cart button.  The function is to be called via a row that corresponds to an item in my product array.

```
<TR>
   <TD>
   <select id="productcategory1" name="productcategory1" onchange="productchange()">
    <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Product # 1 - $1.99</option>
    <option value="2">Product # 2 - $1.99</option>
    <option value="3">Product # 3 - $9.99</option>
    <option value="4">Product # 4 - $9.99</option>
  </select>
  </TD>
  <TD>    

  <div id="test">
  </div>

  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function productchange() 
  {
      var currentrow = $('#productcategory1').val();
      //alert(currentrow);

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themeX/order.php",
        data: "rownum=" + currentrow,
        success: function(currentrow){
            $("#test").html(currentrow);
            }});
      return false;
  }
  </script>

  <?php $rownum = $_GET['test']; ?>
  <?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($products[$rownum]["Product"], $products[$rownum]["Price"]); ?>
  </TD>
  </TR>
```

Order.php:

```
<?php
$rownum = $_GET['rownum'];
echo "Row Number = $rownum";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themeX/order.php",
         data: {'rownum': currentrow},
        success: function(currentrow){
            $("#test").html(currentrow);
            }});
```

Try that.
Also

```
<?php $rownum = $_GET['test']; ?>
```

You dint close the last php and started another..that gives error in first place

Everything is fine in your codes..as far as i see. Have you included jquery library file??

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't appear to change anything.

Comment: Would the issue be with the order.php file or the manner in which I am calling the print_wp_cart_button_for_product in that case?

Comment: I had the second to last php closed in code, but must have missed it when i copied it over to make the post.  I don't receive any errors, but nothing happens when I change my selection with the dropdown menu. However I know the function is being called when I uncomment out the alert.

Comment: Yup.  In my header.  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: hands up.. i just copied ur codes..they work allright. something else is wrong here.

Comment: Strange...well I appreciate the help, not sure what I should do at this point.

Comment: i dont know..is the jquery ur facing problem with...??? whats happening if u remove comments in alert??

Comment: When I remove the comments, the alert box will pop up every time I change my selection on the dropdown menu and inside the alert is the value of the menu selection.

Comment: Looking at it now, I've never debugged like this before.

Comment: Not entirely sure what I'm looking at, but I don't see any errors that appear relevant to the current problem.